# Helloworld webservice using RESTLet

Tags: java, web-services, restlet

Can any one please provide the required setup and steps to develop a sample web service program using RESTLet.

Answer (score 3):

How about the documentation on RESTLets site?

http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/firstSteps#part02